# Find all values for cos(i)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

In my Differential Equations class recently we have learned about Euler's Formula and Fourier Series. I am given the problem `Find all values for cos(i) where i = sqrt(-1)`. There is a long list of similar problems, but I figure if I can get some help on one of them I can learn to do the rest.

If possible, could an answer show me not all the work, but maybe just show me where to start? I want to learn how to get the answers myself, not just be given answers.

TIA!

Comment: $$2\cos(x)=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that is perfect, definitely all I needed! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: There is only one value for $\cos(i)$.  Indeed, $\cos$ is an entire function.  On the other hand, it is a good problem to find all values of $\arccos i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\cos(i)=\frac{e^{i^2}+e^{-i^2}}{2}=\frac{e^{-1}+e}{2}=\frac{1+e^2}{2e}$$

Comment: Would this be considered the most simplified? Becuase I know that `1/2e + e/2` would technically be the same thing.

Comment: It's the same. Then you choose :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. We have the relation$$\cos(\theta+2k\pi)=\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{i(\theta+2k\pi)}+e^{-i(\theta+2k\pi)} \right]$$ for all $k$. Now let $\theta=i$. Our expression becomes $$\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{i(i+2k\pi)}+e^{-i(i+2k\pi)} \right]$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{2k\pi i-1}+e^{-2k\pi i+1} \right]$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{2k\pi i}}{e}+e\cdot e^{-2k\pi i} \right]$$ Now use Euler's formula on each complex exponent inside the brackets. We will get $$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{e^{2k\pi i}}{e}+e\cdot e^{-2k\pi i} \right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)}{e}+e\cdot (\cos(-2k\pi)+i\sin(-2k\pi) )\right]$$ We know $\sin(\pm2k\pi)=0$ for all $k$ so this expression disappears from inside the large brackets. Similarly, we know $\cos(\pm2k\pi)=1$ for all $k$. Plugging this back in should leave us with a final result of $$\cos(i)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1+0}{e}+e\cdot (1+0 )\right] = \frac{1}{2} \left[\frac{1}{e}+e \right]=\frac{1+e^2}{2e}$$ Note: It is important that we let $k$ be arbitrary. This establishes there is precisely one value for $\cos(i)$ which was part of your question.

Comment: very complicate for a such an easy thing !

Comment: It isn't called complex analysis for nothing ;)

Comment: But complex analysis makes things easier, not harder ;-)

Comment: Fo' sho'. In my experience with complex, things can get pretty gnarly with the algebra (as I demonstrated above) but always reduces to an impossibly simple result. I see your answer was far more concise. Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

Too simple, has only one real value.

$\cos(i)= \cosh(i.i) = \cosh(-1)  = \cosh(1) =( e + 1/e)/2$